# Is possible to have the same domain route to different servers without using subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, scalability

I'd like to split my application up onto three different servers. This would make things a little more scalable. But I'm worried about using subdomains since it might mess with our SEO. Is is possible to have the same domain route to 3 different servers without using subdomains? Something like:

```
www.myapp.com/app1
www.myapp.com/app2
www.myapp.com/app3
```

instead of

```
app1.myapp.com
app2.myapp.com
app3.myapp.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a "reverse proxy" to answer requests for `www.myapp.com`, and then forward requests for the various URL prefixes to the various servers that will actually serve requests.

Comment: Would I set that up on a the DNS level? Would route53 be able to handle this?

Comment: No, and No.  Read up on reverse proxies if you need more information on how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Or don't use a reverser proxy and just redirect with 3xx http code inside directory /appx. Google and others bots will follow 3xx codes without problems.